# ServiceStack.Redis SearchKeys

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

I am using the `ServiceStack.Redis` client on C#.

I added about 5 million records of *type1* using the following pattern *a::name::1* and 11 million records of *type2* using the pattern *b::RecId::1*.

Now I am using redis typed client as `client = redis.As<String>`. I want to retrieve all the keys of *type2*. I am using the following pattern:

```cs
var keys = client.SearchKeys("b::RecID::*");
```

But it takes forever (approximately 3-5 mins) to retrieve the keys.

Is there any faster and more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should work hard to avoid the need to scan the keyspace. `KYES` is literally a server stopper, but even if you have `SCAN` available: *don't do that*. Now, you *could* choose to keep the keys of things you have available in a *set* somewhere, but there is no `SRANGE` etc - in 2. you'd have to use `SMEMBERS`, which is still going to need to return a few million records - but at least they will all be available. In later server versions, you have access to `SCAN` (think: `KEYS`) and `SSCAN` (think: `SMEMBERS`), but ultimately you simply have the issue of wanting millions of rows, which is never free.

If possible, you could *mitigate* the impact by using a master/slave pair, and running the expensive operations on the slave. At least other clients will be able to do something while you're killing the server.

Comment: Why are you saying to not use SCAN? It's an O(1) operation and was designed exactly for use in production instead of KEYS.  From the Redis documentation "Since these commands allow for incremental iteration, returning only a small number of elements per call, they can be used in production without the downside of commands like KEYS or SMEMBERS that may block the server for a long time (even several seconds) when called against big collections of keys or elements"

Comment: @MrWiggles it certainly isn't as disruptive as KEYS, but that doesn't mean you can use it casually. You will have a lot of round-trips. In most systems, there will be a lot of unrelated keys, so most of those round trips will be returning nothing. SSCAN would be preferable to SCAN here, storing the keys in a set.

Comment: Why will there be unrelated keys? In this instance you can use the MATCH parameter to only get what you want.  Storing the keys in a set comes with both the memory and maintenance overhead

Comment: @MrWiggles SCAN must still iterate the entire keyspace; it simply *doesn't return you* the ones that don't match; that can mean a lot of empty or near-empty pages, because in order to be O(1) it can only iterate a fixed number per call.

Comment: @MrWiggles from the SCAN documentation: "It is important to note that the MATCH filter is applied after elements are retrieved from the collection, just before returning data to the client. This means that if the pattern matches very little elements inside the collection, SCAN will likely return no elements in most iterations."

Comment: Fair point, I obviously skimmed over that bit, my bad.  But still, I'd like to see benchmarking to justify the overhead of storing keys elsewhere.  In this instance it would be iterating over ~66% of the keyspace so I would opt for simplicity.  If it was a small percentage or I was going for lowest possible latency I would go with your approach

Comment: Ignore my comments and memory overhead, in this specific instance assuming the ID is an incremental number, it's less than 1MB additional

Answer (score 0):

The keys command in Redis is slow (well, not slow, but time consuming).  It also blocks your server from accepting any other command while it's running.

If you really want to iterate over all of your keys take a look at the [scan](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command instead- although I have no idea about ServiceStack for this

Comment: I am using redis 2.6 https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis and this feature is available from 2.8. Thanks

Comment: @alphaCoder please please please do not use `KEYS` (which is, I assume, what `SearchKeys` uses) on a production server; it is a KILLER. No really. Don't do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `SCAN` command, make a loop search, where each search is restricted to a smaller number of keys. For a complete example, refer to this article: http://blog.bossma.cn/csharp/nservicekit-redis-support-scan-solution/